# Capital letters in subcaption numbering

Tags: numbering, subcaption

does anyone know how to (a) and (b) into (A) and (B) in the following example?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
            \centering      
            \includegraphics[scale=.23]{}
            \caption{Picture one}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
             \centering
             \includegraphics[scale=.23]{} 
             \caption{Picture two}
        \end{subfigure}
\caption{Two pictures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Best

Thomas

Comment: `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}` might do

Comment: Your question is part of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17306/caption-labelfont-in-uppercase-what-am-i-doing-wrong so I'll mark this one as duplicate, as the answer there covers the case.